# Url shorting - use http, https or nothing?

Tags: http, https, url-shortener

i was wondering, when shortening urls is it better to short them using http:// or https:// if site supports https or do not use any of them?

Since short urls are external links, i was wondering which benefits and problems will cause if people shares links who points to `site.com` or `http://site.com`  or `https://site.com`

Cause for example http:// works if you do not have https, but https works only if you have https and if one day you want to remove htttps?

Can you explain me the best practice about if use or not protocol declaration in shorten urls?

Comment: shouldn't you use whatever the particular URL shortener supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Https is for Secure connections which uses a set of keys in order to encrypt data. Https uses port 443 while http uses the standard port which is 80. when you type in a site your browser automatically uses port 80, this is why https wont work if you forget it, because it is on port 443 not port 80. When shortening url I recommend that you shorten them using http.

Comment: sure helped a lot thanks, indeed it was what i tought too, just wondering also what if i short urls without http:// or https:// at all

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. What is the URL that you are tying to shorten?

Comment: TinyURL always shorten the links with `https://...` regardless of original URL is http or https. I think the the port number mentioned above is used for the URL shortener service itself rather. Meaning, the URL shortener service itself will use 443 port to get the original URL. So you should be able to always choose `https` which is more secure for your service for all kind of URLs.